# theHarvester returns 0 results

Tags: kali-linux

I have attempted to using the following command on Kali Linux:

```
theharvester -d syngress.com -l 10 -b google
```

Unfortunately, the result I got was nothing. There was no email and host. Is it the problem with my setting of Kali Linux or did I make something wrong?

Comment: Isn't that a web service? I don't think any setting in Kali will influence that except for having a connection to the internet.

Comment: So far, what do you think of the problem? I wish to get some response as well as the result, however I got nothing in return.

Comment: neither bing nor google is working on the latest versions, only linked in

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, haven't been able to isolate the problem.

Tried it with the -b bing option, worked great.

Answer (score 2):

Are you routing your traffic through TOR or proxychanins?

Google may be refusing the requests based on your IP, hence another search "-b" source should work better

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Solved by just adding `-b all`

so:

```
$ theHarvester -d DOMAIN -b all
```

Comment: I get api key errors when i use -b all

Comment: @Crash893 explain the errors. You need APIs, so you need to register to various services like twitter and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
theHarvester -d domain-name -b specify(google)
```

I was facing the same issue, it always returns with some errors like
*Missing the API key for ...*

So I tuned it with the specified `-b` option and it worked.